# How to fire a mouseOver state?

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way I can fire a mouseOver event so that when I hover over a button, other button(s) gets hovered too (e.g. change the icon) ? I work in Java. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could try dispatching an event to the other buttons:

```
button.dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent(...) );
```

Or a better approach is probably:

```
button.getModel().setRollover( true );
```